# Kivy performance degradation over time

Tags: python, python-3.x, frameworks, kivy, kivy-language

I am learning Kivy, and to make it more fun I am creating a small 2D game. For now its just a tank that can be controlled with WASD and shot projectiles with o.

The problem is that the FPS degrades over time. This happens even if I do nothing in the game. I don´t have an FPS counter, but its something like half the FPS after a minute of gametime.

My feeling is that the problem lies somewhere in the updating of canvas in widgets. Since the slowdowns occur even if the player does nothing for the whole game, its seems like there is data somewhere that is just added and added. I don´t know how to better explain it, other than it's weird...

---

A quick overview of how the game is programmed so far:

The main widget is the class Game. It detects keypresses and runs "Clock.schedule_interval-function".

The Tank widget is a child of Game. It holds some data and loads the hull and turret sprites via Kivys Image widget, which becomes its child. It has its own update function that updates everything tank-related, including setting the position of its canvas and rotating the hull and turret image canvas. The update-function in the Tank widget class is invoked by "Clock.schedule_interval" in Game class.

The Shots widget does the same as the Tank widget, only it holds data for each shot fired instead

"Clock schedule_interval"-function holds a list of each shot widget, and deletes them when they get off screen. However, the slowdown problems persist even if no shots are fired.

---

I have attached the complete code. This might be excessive, but I don´t know which part of it that provokes slowdowns. If you want to run the game, just put those four python-files in the same folder, and the images in a sub-folder called "images tank".

I hope someone can take a look at it

main.py:

```
#Import my own modules:
import tank
import shot
from stats import Stats
#Import kivy:
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.clock import Clock

#Set window size properties:
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics','resizable',0)
from kivy.core.window import Window


class Game(Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        #General settings:
        super(Game, self).__init__()
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0/60.0)
        
        #Add keyboard: 
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard (callback=None, target=self, input_type="text")
        #Bind the keyboard to a function:
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self.keypress)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_up=self.keyUp)
        
        #P1 tank starting values:
        self.keypress_p1 = {"forward":False, "backward":False, "left":False, "right":False, "turret_left":False, "turret_right":False, "fire":False}
        
        #P1 tank widget:
        self.tank_p1 = tank.Tank()
        self.add_widget(self.tank_p1)
        
        #P1 shots list:
        self.shotsList_p1 = []
        
        
    #Keyboard press detection:    
    def keypress(self, *args):
        key = args[2]
        if key == "w":
            self.keypress_p1["forward"]=True
        if key == "s":
            self.keypress_p1["backward"]=True
        if key == "a":
            self.keypress_p1["left"]=True
        if key == "d":
            self.keypress_p1["right"]=True
        if key == "q":
            self.keypress_p1["turret_left"]=True
        if key == "e":
            self.keypress_p1["turret_right"]=True
        if key == "o":
            self.keypress_p1["fire"]=True
            
    #Keyboard button up detection:    
    def keyUp(self, *args):
        key = args[1][1]
        if key == "w":
            self.keypress_p1["forward"]=False
        if key == "s":
            self.keypress_p1["backward"]=False
        if key == "a":
            self.keypress_p1["left"]=False
        if key == "d":
            self.keypress_p1["right"]=False
        if key == "q":
            self.keypress_p1["turret_left"]=False
        if key == "e":
            self.keypress_p1["turret_right"]=False
        if key == "o":
            self.keypress_p1["fire"]=False
            
            
    #Parent update function that the clock runs:   
    def update(self, dt):
    
        #Add new shots:
        if self.keypress_p1["fire"]:
            self.shot = shot.Shots(self.tank_p1.my_pos, self.tank_p1.my_angle+self.tank_p1.my_turretAngle)
            self.shotsList_p1.append(self.shot)
            self.add_widget(self.shot)
            self.keypress_p1["fire"] = False
            
        #P1 tank update:
        self.tank_p1.update(self.keypress_p1)
        
        #P1 shot update:
        for i in range(len(self.shotsList_p1)-1,-1,-1):
            self.shotsList_p1[i].update()
            #Remove widgets that are outside the screen:
            if ( 0<=self.shotsList_p1[i].my_pos[0]<Stats.winSize[0] and 0<=self.shotsList_p1[i].my_pos[1]<Stats.winSize[1] )==False:
                self.remove_widget(self.shotsList_p1[i])
                del self.shotsList_p1[i]
            

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = Game()
        Window.size = Stats.winSize
        return game
        
MyApp().run()
```

tank.py:

```
#Import own modules:
from stats import Stats
#import python:
import math
#Import Kivy:
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import PushMatrix, PopMatrix, Rotate, Translate, MatrixInstruction
from kivy.graphics.fbo import Fbo


class Tank(Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Tank, self).__init__()
        
        #Position and rotation values for the tank:
        self.my_pos = [0,0]
        self.posChange = [0,0]
        self.my_angle = 0
        self.angleChange = 0
        self.my_turretAngle = 0
        self.turretAngleChange = 0
        
        #Hull widget:
        self.hull = Hull()
        self.add_widget(self.hull)
        self.hull.center_x = self.my_pos[0]
        self.hull.center_y = self.my_pos[1]
        
        #Turret widget:
        self.turret = Turret()
        self.add_widget(self.turret)
        self.turret.center_x = self.my_pos[0]
        self.turret.center_y = self.my_pos[1]
        
    def update(self, keypress):
        if keypress["forward"]:
            self.my_pos[0] -= Stats.hull_t1["forward"]*math.sin(math.radians(self.my_angle))
            self.my_pos[1] += Stats.hull_t1["forward"]*math.cos(math.radians(self.my_angle))
            self.posChange[0] = -Stats.hull_t1["forward"]*math.sin(math.radians(self.my_angle))
            self.posChange[1] = Stats.hull_t1["forward"]*math.cos(math.radians(self.my_angle))
            
        if keypress["backward"]:
            self.my_pos[0] -= Stats.hull_t1["backward"]*math.sin(math.radians(self.my_angle))
            self.my_pos[1] += Stats.hull_t1["backward"]*math.cos(math.radians(self.my_angle))
            self.posChange[0] = -Stats.hull_t1["backward"]*math.sin(math.radians(self.my_angle))
            self.posChange[1] = Stats.hull_t1["backward"]*math.cos(math.radians(self.my_angle))
             
        if keypress["left"]:
            self.my_angle += Stats.hull_t1["left"]
            self.angleChange = Stats.hull_t1["left"]
            
        if keypress["right"]:
            self.my_angle += Stats.hull_t1["right"]
            self.angleChange = Stats.hull_t1["right"]
            
        if keypress["turret_left"]:
            self.my_turretAngle += Stats.turret_t1["left"]
            self.turretAngleChange = Stats.turret_t1["left"]
            
        if keypress["turret_right"]:
            self.my_turretAngle += Stats.turret_t1["right"]
            self.turretAngleChange = Stats.turret_t1["right"]
            
        
            
        #Tank Position:
        with self.canvas.before:
            PushMatrix()
            Translate(self.posChange[0], self.posChange[1])
        with self.canvas.after:
            PopMatrix()
            
        #Rotate hull image:
        with self.hull.canvas.before:
            PushMatrix()
            self.rot = Rotate()
            self.rot.axis = (0,0,1)
            self.rot.origin = self.hull.center
            self.rot.angle = self.angleChange
        with self.hull.canvas.after:
            PopMatrix()
            
        #Rotate turret image:
        with self.turret.canvas.before:
            PushMatrix()
            self.rot = Rotate()
            self.rot.axis = (0,0,1)
            self.rot.origin = self.turret.center
            self.rot.angle = self.turretAngleChange + self.angleChange
        with self.turret.canvas.after:
            PopMatrix()
        
        #Reset pos, angle and turretAngle change values:
        self.posChange = [0,0]
        self.angleChange = 0
        self.turretAngleChange = 0
        
        
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------            
class Hull(Image):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Hull, self).__init__(source="images tank/Tank.png")
        self.size = self.texture_size
        
class Turret(Image):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Turret, self).__init__(source="images tank/GunTurret.png")
        self.size = self.texture_size
```

shot.py:

```
#Import own modules:
from stats import Stats
#import python:
import math
from copy import copy
#Import Kivy:
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import PushMatrix, PopMatrix, Rotate, Translate, MatrixInstruction
from kivy.graphics.fbo import Fbo

class Shots(Widget):
    
    def __init__(self, tankPos, turretAngle):
        super(Shots, self).__init__()
        #Shot data:
        self.my_pos = copy(tankPos)
        self.my_angle = turretAngle
        self.angleChange = self.my_angle
        self.posChange = [ -Stats.shot_t1["speed"]*math.sin(math.radians(self.my_angle)), Stats.shot_t1["speed"]*math.cos(math.radians(self.my_angle)) ]
        #Add image:
        self.shotImg = ShotImg()
        self.add_widget(self.shotImg)
        self.shotImg.pos = self.my_pos
        self.shotImg.center_x = self.my_pos[0]
        self.shotImg.center_y = self.my_pos[1]
        
        
        
    def update(self):
        self.my_pos[0] += self.posChange[0]
        self.my_pos[1] += self.posChange[1]
        #Shot Position:
        with self.canvas.before:
            PushMatrix()
            Translate(self.posChange[0], self.posChange[1])
        with self.canvas.after:
            PopMatrix()
        
        #Rotate shot image:
        if self.angleChange != 0:
            with self.shotImg.canvas.before:
                PushMatrix()
                self.rot = Rotate()
                self.rot.axis = (0,0,1)
                self.rot.origin = self.shotImg.center
                self.rot.angle = self.angleChange
            with self.shotImg.canvas.after:
                PopMatrix()
            self.angleChange = 0
            
    
class ShotImg(Image):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ShotImg, self).__init__(source="images tank/Bullet.png")
        self.size = self.texture_size
```

stats.py:

```
    class Stats:
    winSize = (800,800)
    hull_t1 = {"forward":2, "backward":-2, "left":2, "right": -2}
    turret_t1 = {"left":5, "right":-5}
    shot_t1 = {"speed":3}
```

images should go in a subfolder called "images tank":

- [Bullet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bY5dw.png)
- [GunTurret](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGE50.png)
- [Tank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znjdx.png)

Answer (score 4):

The way you manage your position will create 8 new instructions per tank, and 6 per shot, every frame, which, at 60fps, will quickly create thousands of instructions, and for kivy will be slower and slower to process them.

```
    #Tank Position:
    with self.canvas.before:
        PushMatrix()
        Translate(self.posChange[0], self.posChange[1])
    with self.canvas.after:
        PopMatrix()
```

you don't want to do that, you want to create one Translate insruction (and same for Rotate) in your widget, and update it, move this block to `__init__` and save Translate to `self.translate` for example, then in update, instead of using posChange, simply do `self.translate.x, self.translate.y = self.my_pos`

apply the same logic for rotation, and for shots, and the performances should be much more stable over time.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately I am away from my computer the next few days, but I will try this when I get back.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, I'm working on a space invaders game and it happened to be the way I treated my logic, I used "with self.canvas"
to draw my widgets, which appeared to be on the long term exhaustive as widgets that get generated on canvas are not being cleared, which is an important thing to be concerned about.

I Fixed it with creating a class for my objects (enemy, bullet, player) and when I need lets say 6 enemies to be created, I create a list of enemy widgets to keep track of them, and them add them to my on my main game widget by using self.add_widget(YourWidgetItem)

and simply when the widget has ended its purpose, like an enemy dying, I set my dead variable for this widget to be true, then scan for dead widgets and remove them from my main game widget by using self.remove_widget(YourWidgetItem)

this is one of many other possible solutions, you just need to take into consideration killing the widget that get off your screen to no overload your game on higher levels

You can check my project if it would help:
https://github.com/steveroseik/Invaders_Game

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32313616)

Comment: I hade the same issue and wanted to share what i think until I find a workaround, which I did and edited my post to be the solution I figured out.